# May placement `new` rely on underlying storage value?

Tags: c++, optimization, language-lawyer

*Let's start with some context.*

A custom memory pool was using code similar to the following:

```
struct FastInitialization {};

template <typename T>
T* create() {
    static FastInitialization const F = {};

    void* ptr = malloc(sizeof(T));
    memset(ptr, 0, sizeof(T));
    new (ptr) T(F);
    return reinterpret_cast<T*>(ptr);
}
```

The idea is that when called with `FastInitialization`, a constructor could assume that the storage is already zero-initialized and therefore only initialize those members who need a different value.

GCC (6.2 and 6.3, at least) however has an "interesting" optimization which kicks in.

```
struct Memset {
    Memset(FastInitialization) { memset(this, 0, sizeof(Memset)); }

    double mDouble;
    unsigned mUnsigned;
};

Memset* make_memset() {
    return create<Memset>();
}
```

Compiles down to:

```
make_memset():
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     edi, 16
        call    malloc
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax], 0
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax+8], 0
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
```

But:

```
struct DerivedMemset: Memset {
    DerivedMemset(FastInitialization f): Memset(f) {}

    double mOther;
    double mYam;
};

DerivedMemset* make_derived_memset() {
    return create<DerivedMemset>();
}
```

Compiles down to:

```
make_derived_memset():
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     edi, 32
        call    malloc
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax], 0
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax+8], 0
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
```

That is, only the first 16 bytes of the `struct`, the part corresponding to its base, have been initialized. Debugging information confirm that the call to `memset(ptr, 0, sizeof(T));` has been completely elided.

On the other hand, both ICC and Clang both call `memset` on the full size, here is Clang's result:

```
make_derived_memset():               # @make_derived_memset()
        push    rax
        mov     edi, 32
        call    malloc
        xorps   xmm0, xmm0
        movups  xmmword ptr [rax + 16], xmm0
        movups  xmmword ptr [rax], xmm0
        pop     rcx
        ret
```

So the behavior of GCC and Clang differ, and the question becomes: is GCC right and producing better assembly, or is Clang right and GCC buggy?

---

Or, in terms of language lawyering:

**Under which circumstances may a constructor rely on the previous value stored in its allocated storage?**

Note: I assume this only matters with placement `new`, but I am happy to be shown otherwise.

Comment: If your code executes memset(ptr, 0, sizeof(T)), and sizeof(T) = 32, and it only zeroes 16 bytes, then obviously something isn't right. Did you try adding some code that reads the member variables after create has been called? What are their values?

Comment: I know this is not the answer to your much broader question; but if it were about initializing with zeros: have you tried out `calloc`, where init with 0 should not be kicked out by the compiler as it might happen with memset?

Comment: @SvenNilsson: The values are left-over from what the memory contained prior to the `memset` call, and since in the real code there were pointers... they were dangling pointers to now freed memory.

Comment: @StephanLechner: Unfortunately uninteresting (for this particular case). This is a minimal reproduction; the real situation, as alluded, is a custom memory pool where memory is allocated once and reused over and over.

Comment: Why bother?  I can't see this could save you any processor cycles unless your object is basically a giant and sparsely filled array.  Even in the case where you are trying to initialize a giant sparse object living inside a memory pool, why not just make an init() method?

Comment: @KevinZ: Why not? The code started as C, so I imagine it's a remainder of the old days, not brought up to C++ standards because nobody saw any harm in it.

Comment: Technically it should be `return new (ptr) T(F);`.  In general these could even be different addresses.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> May placement `new` rely on underlying storage value?

No, it may not. From [dcl.init]:

> If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is default-initialized. When storage for an object
>   with automatic or dynamic storage duration is obtained, the object has an indeterminate value, and if no initialization is performed for the object, that object retains an indeterminate value until that value is replaced (5.18).

Indeterminate value means just that, indeterminate. It does not mean that, in the case of a placement new expression, the previous memory is necessarily maintained. The compiler is allowed to do whatever it wants to the memory - which includes, but is not limited to, nothing.

> Under which circumstances may a constructor rely on the previous value stored in its allocated storage?

The subsequent paragraph in [dcl.init] lists cases where the behavior is *not* undefined when producing an indeterminate value, but they only have to do with unsigned narrow character types.

So, under no circumstances.

Comment: The interesting thing here is that the memory is NOT SUPPOSED to be in an indeterminate state: it was explicitly 0-initialized, but GCC apparently decided that since a constructor was going to be executed this 0-initialization was unnecessary.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Sure, post-constructor it's indeterminate, so it's a valid optimization.

Comment: That's what I suspected, do you know if there is any indication that PODs/trivial layout/standard layout types may be exempt?

Comment: @MatthieuM. There are no exemptions.

Comment: I would say that the `memset` causes undefined behaviour. However the C++ standard only defines memset by reference to the C standard, which has a different memory model, so it is murky.  (A loop to write zero-valued chars into the space certainly would cause UB)

Answer (score 1):

Both GCC and Clang are correct - leaving the (own) data members of `DerivedMemset` uninitialized will result in undefined behavior as soon as their values are accessed. Therefore the compiler is given the license to leave - right before the constructor is invoked - any bit pattern at the storage range that will be occupied by those fields.

Comment: In answers for questions with the language lawyer tag, it is generally expected to back up one's claims with quotes from the C++ Standard. Specifically, in this case, I wonder if the answer differs from Trivial Types (which can be copied by `memcpy`), Standard Layout Types and PODs (an whether `DerivedMemset` qualifies as either of those 3) vs "full-blown" classes.

Comment: True, but this answer actually makes sense. It is a bit unexpected that your manual efforts to zero the memory before placement new can be ignored by the compiler. But if the standard says that the compiler is allowed to create any kind of random junk in the uninitialized members, that is still okay I guess.